# Ninja Forms not working with jQuery 3.1.1

Tags: jquery, wordpress, ninja-forms

I'm using jQuery 3.1.1 on one of our sites, as this is required for Slick slider. But when I update WordPress to use the most recent version of jQuery then the conditional logic on the form stops working.

Ninja Forms has told me that this is because I'm running two versions of jQuery, but I'm definitely not - I'm only pulling in jQuery 3.1.1.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js?ver=3.1.1.1553503584'></script>
```

Comment: Press `F12` & focus in the `console` tab clear the errors & hit refresh. You should be seeing some JS errors in the console,please post them in the question.

Comment: Also (again referring to the Developer Tools in Chrome) look at the `Sources` tab and verify that there is indeed only one version of jQuery in use. (The point being that even if you directly pull in the new version, it's easy to pull in an old version indirectly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that the Ninja Forms is currently only compatible with the WordPress builtin jQuery version, have a look here (https://github.com/wpninjas/ninja-forms-conditional-logic/issues/237) and here (https://github.com/wpninjas/ninja-forms-conditional-logic/issues/234). I hope, they fix this soon...

A response from their support team was:
Ninja Forms only works with the version of jquery that is included with WordPress, version 1.12.4

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions if they want to use Ninja Forms as well as other functionality that depends on jQuery 3.x.x. ?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed my Ninja form wouldn't load when I updated to the latest version of jQuery which led me to find this post. However, it loads and works with 2.2.4 when enqueued in functions.php.